# Run program with os.system(<program>) that expects user input in pyhton

Tags: python, command-line, stdout, stdin

So I have a python-file where I call a program that I normally run on the command line.
This program, when executed from the command-line, expects some inputs by the user. In this case I just want to hit enter.
How can I handle this so that python can automatically "hit" enter?

Comment: If you want to control stdin, use `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run` instead of `os.system`. The `communicate()` call lets you pass stdin contents as an argument.

Comment: `os.system()` generally should be avoided -- it's difficult to use with parameterized argument lists without introducing security bugs.

Comment: thanks a lot for those helps! os.system just seems so easy, that's why I used it...